# Align table horizontally - rescale

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, scaling

I would like to align horizontally two tables, if necessary rescaling them, to put them on the same line.
Obviously even the caption must be scaled, remaining aligned with the center of the table.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{SSS} 
\toprule {Col A} & {Col B} & {Col C} \\ 
\midrule 
1 & 2 & 3000000.000 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6000000.000 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\caption[loftitle]{Title 1} 
\end{table}

\begin{table} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{SSS} 
\toprule {Col D} & {Col E} & {Col F} \\ 
\midrule 
7 & 8 & 9000000.000 \\ 
10 & 11 & 12000000.000 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\caption[loftitle]{Title 2, longer than the width of the table} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If they should be aligned,  both shouldn't float, should they?

Comment: I removed [htp] from both, it was a remnant of the first version.
Btw, I guess I can aling horizontally tables even with that addition...

Comment: You need to put both tabulars into one table (note, one table can also have two captions, but to put them side by side you will need two minipages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right about having to resize the tabulars to fit side by side.

[image: tabulars]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}% or graphicx

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{SSS} 
\toprule {Col A} & {Col B} & {Col C} \\ 
\midrule 
1 & 2 & 3000000.000 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6000000.000 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}}\hfil
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{SSS} 
\toprule {Col D} & {Col E} & {Col F} \\ 
\midrule 
7 & 8 & 9000000.000 \\ 
10 & 11 & 12000000.000 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\caption[loftitle]{Title 1}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\caption[loftitle]{Title 2, longer than the width of the table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps consider using `\begin{tabular}[t]`...

Comment: @Werner - Or rescale both to the same factor.  There are lots of options.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `\captionbox` provided by `caption.sty`.  You can resize the width of tables with `{0.49\linewidth}` acc. to your needs.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{%
  aboveskip=3pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  labelfont={scriptsize,bf},
  textfont={scriptsize,it},
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[!h]
  \footnotesize\centering 
  \captionbox[Short title]{Title 1}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{0.49\linewidth}{@{}SXS[table-format = 7.3]@{}}
    \toprule {Col A} & {Col B} & {Col C} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3000000.000 \\
    4 & 5 & 6000000.000 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}}%
  \hfill
  \captionbox[Long title]{Title 2, longer than the width of the table
    so that you get a line break}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{0.49\linewidth}{@{}SXS[table-format = 8.3]@{}}
    \toprule {Col D} & {Col E} & {Col F} \\
    \midrule
    7  & 8  & 9000000.000 \\
    10 & 11 & 12000000.000 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reduce the font size of the tabular material. Just use 2 side-by-side `minipage`s and use the `table-format` option of the `siunitx` package to properly center the material in the third column of each table. And, se the `[t]` positioning directive for both `minipage` environments.

(The horizontal line in the image below is there just to illustrate the width of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}SSS[table-format=7.3]} 
\toprule {Col A} & {Col B} & {Col C} \\ 
\midrule 
1 & 2 & 3000000.000 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6000000.000 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\caption[loftitle]{Title 1} 
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}SSS[table-format=8.3]} 
\toprule {Col D} & {Col E} & {Col F} \\ 
\midrule 
7 & 8 & 9000000.000 \\ 
10 & 11 & 12000000.000 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\caption[loftitle]{Title 2, longer than the width of the table} 
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```